# If I say "I was happy yesterday", does that always imply "I am not happy today"?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, present-simple

I have some feelings (**through the ways they answered my question**) that some native speakers always think the following:

If we say "**I was happy yesterday**", that implies "**I am not happy today**"?

Maybe my feeling was wrong.

**The USE 1:** Simple past is used to show a completed action in the past & we know the time that the action completed.[Source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html)

*I saw a movie yesterday.*

**The USE 2:** But the Simple Past can also be used to describe past facts or generalizations which are no longer true. [Source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html)

So, when we say "*He didn't like tomatoes before.*", we imply that "*Now he likes tomatoes*"

Now, come back to the sentence "**I was happy yesterday**". It could mean:

**The USE 1:** that feeling completed in the past (Maybe, my girlfriend kissed me yesterday & therefore I felt happy at that time). But, today "*I am still happy*" (Maybe because I won a lottery, for example).

**The USE 2:** when you say  "**I was happy yesterday**" you may contrast with the current situation. It could mean "**I was happy yesterday but today I am not happy**".

So, If I say "**I was happy yesterday**", does that always imply "**I am not happy today**"?

Also, What about "**I was married 2 years ago.**"?

Let say 2 years ago I got a wedding with a lady & now that lady & I still live happily together. We can say "**I am married**" = "**I have a wife now**".

But can we say "**I was married 2 years ago.**" but Now "**I am still married**". Does "**I was married 2 years ago.**" imply "**I divorced**"?

Answer (score 3):

There's *implies*, and then there's *entails*.  When you say "always implies", I think you mean "entails".

Without further context, the sentence

> I was happy yesterday.

implies but does not entail that your period of happiness has ended.

Implication and inference are soft, fuzzy things.  That's the reason that we have those two words:  I can imply something that you don't manage to infer.  I can infer something that you don't mean to imply.  There is no necessary connection between them.

Entailment is an essential, unavoidable thing.  It's a consequence.  If one thing entails another, that relationship is as strong and as certain as the relationship between *cause* and *effect*.

> I am miserable today.  I have no idea why.  I was happy yesterday.
>
> I was happy yesterday.  I am happy today.  I plan to still be happy tomorrow.

Context makes a difference.  In the first series, today's misery stands in contrast to yesterday's happiness.  We are certain that the period of happiness has ended.  In the second, there is only one period of happiness that extends from the past, through the present, and possibly into the future.

I would not expect any native speaker to have a problem with either series of sentences above.

Comment: It might be worth noting [Grice's maxim of relation](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~haroldfs/dravling/grice.html) - *where one tries to be **relevant,** and says things that are pertinent to the discussion.* Granted, "happiness" is a somewhat flexible state (*I'm not happy* usually means *I'm unhappy*, but it's perfectly possible to say *I'm not **unhappy**, but I'm not happy either*). But unless the speaker's state of mind ***yesterday*** is being implicitly contrasted with how he is ***today***, it makes about as much sense as, say, *I was 6 feet tall yesterday* (and as you can see, I still am).

Comment: A comedian says "I used to do drugs -- still do, but I *used to*".  Funny, but (I assume intentionally) wrong.  There is an entailment there -- "used to" is used when the custom or habit has ended.  That's different than "I did drugs -- still do, but I did".  The relevant distinction is that "I did drugs" merely implies that you stopped, but "I used to do drugs" entails that you stopped -- even if you've started again.

Comment: Yeah, well - like I say, "being happy" is flexible as to whether that it's a relatively continuous state *(I didn't like my old job, but I'm happy working here)* or a short-lived response to something ephemeral *(I'm happy to see you still know how to treat a lady!*). And even your *I did drugs* could be *...for years* or *...only once*.

Comment: The question is whether saying that I was in some state yesterday always implies that I am not in the same state today.  We could make [Futurama's Hermes Conrad](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/0e/0e61b1d9aae8e633c50773d7db1e0555cc2156894d82b0033767f59341b83981.jpg) very proud by saying "yes", or we can give a useful answer.  The remaining relevant points are that "implies" does not mean "entails" and that the simple past tense, no matter how strongly it implies an end, doesn't entail one.  On that note, I hope to leave the substance and nature of happiness to philosophers and neuroscientists.

Comment: My first thought on reading the actual *question* was "This is more to do with common sense than the use of English" (or any other language, come to that). In which context I note that as of right now no-one (even *you*, who posted an answer) has upvoted the question. But your "implies / entails" distinction is so relevant (sorry! :) that I'll probably end up closing some future "Does X always imply Y?" questions in favour of this one. It really is a point well made, with or without explicit reference to Grice.

Comment: Thank you, @FumbleFingers -- not just for the compliment but also for reminding me how fuzzy the borders on the intellectual landscape can be.  When reasoning in or about a given language, it's not easy to find where language ends and pure reason begins.  On my cognitive map, the country of pure reason is labeled *HIC SVNT LEONES*.

Comment: Lions, huh? I was fascinated a few months ago when I first saw some of those [AI dream images](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BQSnrDAraQ) effectively conveying "essence of cat". You and I have "cognitive maps" that probably only overlap at certain points, but I will be *really* interested to see if one of these top-end neural nets manages to come up with an "objective" ontological map of all things known to Man, and how they interrelate (by hoovering up and correlating the entire contents of the web, a project which seems at least *theoretically feasible* to me).

Comment: The liberal elite would have us believe politics has become dramatically "polarised" (citing Brexit, Trump, etc., as "extreme popularism"). But the reality is that for *decades* the main parties in advanced democracies have been moving towards the political centre (sometimes making it hard to differentiate between them). If Swift were writing today, perhaps the major factions in Lilliput would all be in agreement that we should open and serve our eggs ***sideways on*** (and they'd all be telling us we're getting the best of both worlds by making a sensible compromise! :)

Comment: The mods will probably tidy this interaction up anyway (though we might get ticked off). But I think a certain amount of stuff like this does no real harm, and might actually be helpful sometimes - if we know a bit more about how each other thinks, sometimes that will help us reach points of agreement as regards things that really *are* fully on topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62929/discussion-between-gary-botnovcan-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: What about "I was married 2 years ago."? Let say 2 years ago I got a wedding with a lady & now that lady & I still live happily together. So, we can say "I am married" = "I have a wife now". But can we say "I was married 2 years ago." but Now "I am still married". Does "I was married 2 years ago." imply "I divorced"?

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand my point.  "I am married" *implies* that I have a wife.  But, it only entails that I have a spouse.  If you later discover that I have a husband instead of a wife, or a harem instead of just *one* wife, well, maybe I surprised you, confused you, or even mislead you, but I didn't lie.

Comment: Maybe a real-world example might help, @Tom.  "I am married" implies that I am not divorced, just as "I am divorced" implies that I am not married.  "I have two wives", of course, implies that I'm a bigamist.  The truth is that I'm not a bigamist: I do have two wives, I am married, *and* I am divorced.  If you're going to make sense of that at all, then you have to *ignore* at least a few of those implications.  In my case, I'm happily divorced from my first wife, happily married to my second wife, and there is no point in my personal history when the two marriages overlapped.

Comment: Could "I was married 2 years ago." have 2 implications? -1st implication: 2 years ago I got a wedding with a lady & now that lady & I still live happily together. or - 2nd implication: "I am divorced".

Answer (score 0):

In conversations one generally expects the other party to provide complete information.

Consider these examples:

1. Did you like the meal [Burger, Fries and Salad]? - I liked the salad.
2. Do you like Star Wars? - I like the original trilogy.
3. Are you [generally] happy? - I was happy yesterday.

The question is about a larger scope, the answer takes extra effort (i.e. is not simply "yes") to narrow the scope to one aspect. This implies that what is asked is not true in general (or at least requires qualification).

It could also be interpreted as evasion:

1. Do you have a car? - I have a bike.
2. Do you have children? - I have a dog.
3. Are you married [now]? - I was married two years ago.

Again, you put in extra effort (both in terms of extra words and in terms of letting the conversation not go as smoothly) to not say yes, so it is implicitly negates the original question.